# Insert Listbox Items to SQL Database table while keeping Identity column constant

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following code.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = WOOLSVALLEG\MEGASUL; Initial Catalog = POSListDB2; Integrated Security = True");
for (int k = 0; k < listBox1.Items.Count; k++)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO POStable2(L"+k+") Values(@L"+k+")", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L" + k +"", listBox1.Items[k].ToString());
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

I want to insert each time an item of listbox into column of database table. I need identity column too. But the problem is it adds data diagonally as it updates each the loop iterate. How I can add for example 5 items from listbox into 5 columns of database table  while the identity column remain same for the loop operation. 
Thanks

this is what I got;

[image]

Comment: Don't put `k` into your parameter for selecting the column as `k` increases in each loop. Just hard code the column names.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the listbox items varying each time an order is processed. So I don't know how much column I should hardcode in the table.

Comment: Can you put an example of what you mean into your question? I understand the concept but the specifics are hard to follow.

Comment: Listbox items vary in number each time a transaction is made. How i can know the exact number of columns in database table for each transaction which can store data from each items in listbox?

Comment: I don't know until you show an example in your question, it's too hard to understand what your listbox looks like from one sentence in the comments...

Comment: Can you show listbox us? I wont to see your Listbox`s rows and colums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a single insert statement and execute it only once. 
One way to do it is like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Connection = connection;
command.Parameters.Clear();
var sql = "INSERT INTO POStable2(";
var values = "Values(";
for (int k = 0; k < listBox1.Items.Count; k++)
{
    sql = sql + "L" + k + ",";
    values = values + "@L" + k + ",";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L" + k +"", listBox1.Items[k].ToString());

}
sql = sql.TrimEnd(",") + ") " + values.TrimEnd(",") + ") ";
command.CommandText = sql;
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

I didn't test it, of course. You might want to put a brakepoint before opening the connection and check the sql you get.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks